# $G$ has normal subgroup of order 5

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $x^5-7$ over $Q$ and let $G=\text{Gal}(L/Q)$

(I) Prove that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $5$

(II) Prove that $G$ has a subgroup of order $4$ that is not normal.

[You can use that $[L:Q]=20$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $x^5-7$ are irreducible over $Q$]

---

I think $L=(7^{\frac15}, \xi)$ where $\xi=e^{\frac{2\pi}{5}i}$.

I am stuck on both parts of the question.

Degree of the galois group is $20$. I am guessing $L$ is the splitting field of $x^5-7$ over $Q$ and splitting fields are normal extensions so $G$ has a subgroup that is normal. The degree of the polynomial is five so it is of order five.

For the second part I have no idea.

Comment: Hint: Think about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galois group of this polynomial is of order $\;5\cdot4=20\;$ , and it isn't abelian since it has a non-normal extension of order $\;5\;$ , namely $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]7)/\Bbb Q\;$ .

Exactly because of this reason and the Galois correspondence, there is a non-normal subgroup of order $\;20/5=4\;$ .

Now you do the rest, observing we have a *normal extension* $\;\Bbb Q(\xi)/\Bbb Q\;$ . Can you see what its order is?

Comment: So $G_1=Gal(Q(\xi)/Q)$ is a subgp of G and this is normal because $Q(\xi)$ is the splitting field for the irreducible polynomial $x^5-7$. $[Q(\xi):Q]=5$ using this polynomial so $G_1$ has degree 5. And then for the other part: $Gal(Q(7^{1/5})/Q)$ is a subgp of G, it has degree 4 since $[Q(7^{1/5}:Q]=4$ using the degree 4 irreducible polynomial given. It is not normal because some of the roots of the polynomial are not contained in $Q(7^{1/5})$? Is this correct?

Comment: @cooldudeman No,  we must be careful here:  $\;\Bbb Q(\xi)\;$ cannot be the splitting field of $\;x^5-7\;$ over the rationals since it doesn't contain any of its roots, beginning (but not only)  with $\;\sqrt[5]7\;$ itself. Yet, it is the splitting field of $\;x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)\;$ , so its corresponding subgroup in the Galois group of the above polynomial is normal.

Comment: Oh so it must contain at least 1 root in the rationals right?

Comment: @cooldudeman No. To be called "the splitting field of the polynomial $\;f(x)\in F[x]\;$ it **must** contain *all the roots* of $\;f(x)\;$ and *also be the minimal field extension* of $\;F\;$ that contains them all.

Comment: Is what I wrote for the second part of the question correct?

Comment: @cooldudeman If you mean that $\;L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]7,\,\xi)\;$ is *the* splitting fielf of $\;x^5-7\;$ over  $\;\Bbb Q\;$ , then yes: that is the splitting field of that rational polynomial. By the way, in your comment above: we have that $\;[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]7\,:\,\Bbb Q]=5\;$ , **not** $\;4\;$ as you wrote.

Comment: Actually I am confused. The extension $Q(\xi)$ over $Q$ is normal because it is the splitting field of $x^5-1$ over $Q$. But it could have been the splitting field for $x^7-1$ or $x^n-1$. So how can we know the order?

Comment: @cooldudeman Perhaps your knowledge of this stuff isn't yet as required to cope with this question: $\;\Bbb Q(\xi)\;$ is the splitting field of $\;x^5-1\;$ because it contains **all** its roots and it is the minimal such field that does so. It cannot be the splitting field of anything else over the rationals since $\;\xi^5=1\;$ , but $\;\xi^7\neq1\;$ , say.  And $\;\xi^n=1\iff n\;$ is a multiple of $\;5\;$ , **but then** $\;\Bbb Q(\xi)\;$ may not be **the minimal** such one!

Comment: oh sorry! I thought $xi$ was e to the 2pi I!

Comment: @cooldudeman **You** defined $\;\xi\;$ in your question, not I... :)

Comment: I know sorry. OK I fully understand part (I) thanks! With the next part, the extension $Q(7^{1/5}=A)$ over $Q$ has degree $5$. This extension is not normal because why??

Comment: Is it because the polynomial $x^5-7$ has roots that are not in the Q(A)? But then how is the order of the subgp 4?

Comment: You said in the first part of your answer that it contains a non normal extension but how did you even know that was the case...

Comment: OK is it because $Q(A)$ is not normal because the polynomial $x^5-7$ contains roots over Q outside of $Q(A)$. So this field is of order 5. And because the order of G is 20, 20/5=4 which is the order of the subgp that is not normal.

Comment: @cooldudeman Exactly. you got it now.